# conventions to implementing an interface in android?

Tags: java, android

take for example

```
private onClickListener mCorkeyListener = new onClickListener() {    
         public void onClick(View v) {
         } 
};
```

straight from the android website. so what's the convention behind it exactly. i know it may sound a bit ambiguous, but bear w/ it.

Comment: you have a typo in *but bear w/ it.*

Comment: I do not understand the question? is there a question?

Comment: THis isn't an android question, its a question about Java.  This is an annonymous class.

Answer (score 0):

it is [anonymous class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html), you are defining new class and its implementation